# Importing a .csv with headers that show up as first row of data

Tags: r, import, header, row

I'm importing a csv file into R. I read a post here that said in order to get R to treat the first row of data as headers I needed to include the call `header=TRUE`.

I'm using the import function for RStudio and there is a Code Preview section in the bottom right. The default is:

```
library(readr)
existing_data <- read_csv("C:/Users/rruch/OneDrive/existing_data.csv")
View(existing_data)
```

I've tried placing `header=TRUE` in the following places:

- `read_csv(header=TRUE, "C:/Users...)`
- `existing_data.csv", header=TRUE`
- after 2/existing_data.csv")

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The checkbox *"First Row as Names"* is marked, so you should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `col_names` instead of `header`. Try this:

```
library(readr)
existing_data <- read_csv("C:/Users/rruch/OneDrive/existing_data.csv", col_names = TRUE)
```

There are two different functions to read csv files (actually far more than two): `read.csv` from `utils` package and `read_csv` from `readr` package. The first one gets `header` argument and the second one `col_names`.

You could also try `fread` function from `data.table` package. It may be the fastest of all.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is one variable name that is correctly identified as a variable name (notice your first column). I would guess that your first row *only* contains the variable "Existing Product List", and that your other variable names are actually contained in the second row. Open the file in Excel or LibreOffice Calc to confirm.

If it is indeed the case that all of the variable names you've listed (including "Existing Product List") are in the first row, then you're in the same boat as me. In my case, the first row contains all of my variables, however they appear as both variable names **and** the first row of observations. Turns out the encoding is messed up (which could also be your problem), so my solution was simply to remove the first row.

```
library(readr)
mydat = read_csv("my-file-path-&-name.csv")
mydat = mydat[-1, ]
```